# Deserializing JSON object throws a Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException

Tags: c#, json

I have this Json object:

```
{
   "Sheet1": [
      {
         "one": 1,
         "two": 18
      },
      {
         "one": 16,
         "two": 33
      },
      {
         "one": 17,
         "two": 34
      }
   ]
}
```

And I am trying to deserialize it using the following model:

```
public class Sheets
{
    [JsonProperty("Sheet1")]
    public Sheet Sheet { get; set; }
}

public class Sheet
{
    public List<Row> Rows { get; set; }
}

public class Row
{
    [JsonProperty("one")]
    public string Col1 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("two")]
    public string Col2 { get; set; }
}

var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Sheets>(result);
```

but I'm getting this exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
>
> Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'ExcelConsoleApp.Sheet' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

What am I doing wrong? Any thoughts?

**EDIT**

One possible solution is to use

```
dynamic dynamicObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);
```

but I want to deserialize it directly into my model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Sheet1` is **not a Sheet type** but a **List of Rows**. This can be identify by brackets.
i.e `"Sheet1": [` which is a clear sign for **Collection** and not an Object which is identified by `{`.

Change *Sheets* to the following:

```
public class Sheets
{
    [JsonProperty("Sheet1")]
    public List<Row> Sheet { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: No problem, be advised that i would change the property `List<Row> Sheet` to be more accurate, something like `List<Row> Rows`

Answer (score 2):

this is the model you need, I tested it and it was working exactly as you want.
and there is NO need to change the JSON structure.

```
public class SheetRoot
{
    [JsonProperty("Sheet1")]
    public List<Row> Sheet { get; set; }
}

public class Row
{
    [JsonProperty("one")]
    public int Col1 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("two")]
    public int Col2 { get; set; }
}

var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SheetRoot>(s);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Hakam, it looks good to me, but I'm not sure why I'm getting `An unhandled exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll`

Comment: @HoomanYar I updated the answer to make better names of the classes and properties. I could not figure out why the old code is producing that exception on your machine ,it was working correctly on mine without any exception and the result was correct.

Comment: after naming the classes better I know my answer is very like the accepted answer, but I just does not intended this

Answer (score 0):

As error shown you should use a list instead of `Sheet` class.
Try this:

```
     {"Sheets" :
       { 
       "Sheet1": [
          {
             "one": 1,
             "two": 18
          },
          {
             "one": 16,
             "two": 33
          },
          {
             "one": 17,
             "two": 34
          }
       ]
     }
    }
```

Comment: Well thanks but that's a different json object that what I have

Comment: You can change your class in this statement too: `var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Sheet>(result);`

Comment: that's actually the problem. It'll retrun null result using that code since `Sheet` is like an inner object to it

Answer (score 0):

Your structures are incompatible.

Inferring from the JSON, the example object can be traversed as `Sheet1[i].one` or `Sheet1[i].two`. `i` being the index. Whereas, the C# model that you have posted will be traversed as `SheetsObj.Sheet.Row[i].Col1`.

You could try changing your JSON or model.
So, maybe change your JSON to

```
{
    "Sheet1" : {
        "Rows": [
            {
             "one": 1,
             "two": 18
            },
            {
             "one": 16,
             "two": 33
            },
            {
             "one": 17,
             "two": 34
            }
       ]
    }
}
```

Comment: No problem, but then, Hakam Fostok's answer should do it.